# Resizing a js chart in shiny app

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am using a gauge widget from c3 library.

It's function are composed by 3 elements:

```
function(Value, width, height)
```

When I try to generate the dashboard, the result is this one:

[image: Gauge]

I am using this layout:

```
splitLayout(C3GaugeOutput("gauge1","auto","auto"),
                              C3GaugeOutput("gauge2","auto","auto"),
                              C3GaugeOutput("gauge3","auto","auto"))
```

I tryied changed the dimensions, but this side bar still appears.

The C3 code is the following:

```
HTMLWidgets.widget({

  name: 'C3Gauge',

  type: 'output',

  factory: function(el, width, height) {

    return {

        renderValue: function(x) {

        // Check if we have a reference to our chart
        if(typeof(el.chart) == 'undefined'){
            // create a chart and set options
            // note that via the c3.js API we bind the chart to the element with id equal to chart1
            var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: el,
                data: {
                    json: x,
                    type: 'gauge',
                },
                gauge: {
                    label:{
                        //returning here the value and not the ratio
                        format: function(value, ratio){ return value;}
                    },
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    width: 15,
                    units: '%' //this is only the text for the label
                }
            });

          el.chart = chart;

        }else{

          // Update the chart if it already exists
          el.chart.load({json: x});
        }

      },

      resize: function(width, height) {

        // TODO: code to re-render the widget with a new size

      }

    };
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Using `box()` function:

```
fluidRow(box(C3GaugeOutput("gauge1","auto","auto")),
                              box(C3GaugeOutput("gauge2","auto","auto")),
                              box(C3GaugeOutput("gauge3","auto","auto")))
```